# Show uncertainty about isocontour in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, probability, contour

I'm currently working with uncertainty visualization, using Python / Matplotlib, and I would like to be able to display the uncertainty about an isocontour in 2D. I will try to be more specific:

- As input, I have N realizations of a scalar field.
- These realizations are simulations of the same experiment.
- For each of these N realizations, I have an isocontour.

Given that, I know that I can display the contour using the `plt.contour` function.
However, what I would like to do is to map each possible contour (by level) to a color map showing its probability of happening, something like its positional uncertainty. I.e, each one of the contour levels would be mapped to a color to represent its probability of happening.

It is possible to do that somehow? I don't know how I could verify if, for each contour at level **b** through **n** realizations, they are the same or not.

Comment: Are you looking for [something like a heat map](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) (see the last plot)?

Comment: Kind of. I would like to have a heat map for the contour lines. I.e., each contour line at some level would have a color associated with it representing how many times it has happening in N realizations. Then, the contour lines would not have a fixed color representing its level, but this stability over the realizations.

Comment: I think you first need to find a way to compare if two paths overlap. With your current code, two paths may *look* the same, but Python will treat the Paths as different objects (as you alluded at the end of your question). I don't have a ready solution for this, and it is deserving of being a question of its own: Given two paths, how can you determine if they are visually similar. Note that you can not just compare vertices, because the vertices could come in a different order, or there could be a 1000 verts in one path and 100 in the other...

Comment: Next, it appears you want to color the contour *one single color* depending on the frequency with which it appears. In that case, you do not need `colorline` at all. You could do that with `plt.plot` if there aren't too many (e.g. thousands) of lines. But that's a much easier problem to fix. I'm going to delete my answer below since it solves a different problem than the one you are facing.